# Short powershell command download and run

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

Whats the shortest code to download and execute a file inpowershell?

Comment: This would be better on-topic in CodeReview. Anyhow, you got three files to download, so three download commands are needed. The script is quite simple and easy to read, so shortening it might be of little benefit. Why would you like to shorten it?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I am eager to learn more about powershell and optimizing my code.

Comment: don't edit the question that changes its meaning significantly

Answer (score 0):

The old adage is to avoid optimization unless there's a need for it. Programs should empathize readability. If the code is hard to understand, any bugs are easily camouflaged by the complexity. As one of the old masters put it:

> The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times; premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming.
>
> -Donald Knuth

That being said, your sample can be optimized - by making it more *readable* and *maintainable*. The performance is not going to change; the slowest part by far would be fetching the remote files.

Consider, say

```
$arr= @() #Empty array
$arr += new-object psobject -property @{"Src"="z:\monthlypayments.txt"; "Dst" = "monthend.txt"} # Add custom object for monthly into the array
$arr += new-object psobject -property @{"Src"="z:\weekly.txt"; "Dst" = "weekend.txt"} # Same for weekly

$arr # Print the array for illustration purposes

Src                    Dst
---                    ---
z:\monthlypayments.txt monthend.txt
z:\weekly.txt          weekend.txt

# Now that we have seen the data, let's use it    
$wc = New-Object net.webclient
$arr | % {  # Iterate through the array
    $wc.DownloadFile($_.Src, $_.Dst) # Download items
}
```

So what is done is the source and destination data items are bind together in a data structure. Source and destination are no longer a bunch of strings but properties of an object. The objects are stored in an array. In order to process all the objects, the array can be iterated with `Foreach-Object` (aka `%`) which will read array elements one by one and send those to the pipeline. The `$_` means the current object on the pipeline - the element the foreach statement has picked from the array.

By using this approach, WebClient's DownloadFile doesn't need to worry about hard-coded paths. It will read them from the piped object's attributes `.Src` and `.Dst`.

Now, this is clearly overkill an approach for downloading two files. But what if you got twenty to process? Then it would be much more easy to maintain the source-destination pairs in the beginning of the script where all the source and destination tuples are added in the array.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I sincerely appreciate it. While I love your edit, and i learnt from it, initially all I wanted to know is if I have to repeat "New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile" for every download? And/Or, is there a shorter form of this command. For example, instead of "command" we can use "cm" in powershell. But is there a shorter form for New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile ?

Comment: You could use the `$wc.DownloadFile()` a few times instead of creating new objects. I still fail to see any reason for trying to find shorter forms. Easy to read is a good thing.